# SSL on Heroku, error add cert: "not valid. The 'Not After' date restriction on the certificate has passed."

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, heroku

I purchased a wildcard SSL cert from Gandi.net many months ago, and used it immediately after purchase successfully on other hosting services than Heroku. I now need to secure a new subdomain on a Heroku hosted app.

Following these instructions...

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#provision-the-add-on

...I entered:

```
$ heroku certs:add ~/Desktop/certificate-32703.crt ~/Desktop/private.key
Resolving trust chain... done
Adding SSL Endpoint to dp-heroku-ssl... failed
!    Certificate is no longer valid. The 'Not After' date restriction on the certificate has passed.
```

The certificate itself isn't set to expire until 2017.

The only reference to a "Not After" parameter I've found:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/verify.html

> The final operation is to check the validity of the certificate chain. The validity period is checked >against the current system time and the notBefore and notAfter dates in the certificate. The >certificate signatures are also checked at this point.

I've opened a ticket with Gandi and with Heroku. I'll post any useful response from either.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is very vendor-specific and is best directed to the vendor's support.

Comment: As stated, I have done so. It would be useful to understand this "Not After" parameter. Should I rephrase the question to make this more clear (and therefore less vendor specific)?

Comment: The "Not After" date is the time when the certificate expires.

Answer (score 1):

Embarrassingly, it was telling me something simple: the certificate was expired. The certificate I THOUGHT it was is NOT expired. But I had the wrong .crt file. It was for a different certificate that IS expired. #facepalm

Once I used the correct .crt file, it worked immediately.

Comment: We could have been a lot more helpful if you'd posted the certificate!